# How to accept a list into an SQL TableAdapter query using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, tableadapter

I'd like to perform an SQL query on a data table and return records with IDs that match any one of the IDs in a particular list (which would be passed in as a parameter to the SQL TableAdapter query). This ID which is being checked is a foreign key in the table. The following is the code am I using, only including what is relevant:

```
SELECT BookingID, DogID
FROM Booking
WHERE DogID IN (...)
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to pass in a list of type string.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass id as `,` separated string and use User Define function to split that:

try below:

UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Udf_stringtolist] (@List      NVARCHAR(max), 
                                          @Delimeter NVARCHAR(10)) 
returns @tmpListTable TABLE ( 
  value NVARCHAR(max)) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @DelimPosition INT 

      SELECT @DelimPosition = Charindex(@Delimeter, @List) 

      WHILE @DelimPosition > 0 
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO @tmpListTable 
                        (value) 
            VALUES     (Cast(Ltrim(Rtrim(LEFT(@List, @DelimPosition - 1))) AS 
                             VARCHAR( 
                             100))) 

            SELECT @List = RIGHT(@List, Len(@List) - @DelimPosition), 
                   @DelimPosition = Charindex(@Delimeter, @List) 
        END 

      IF Len(@List) > 0 
        INSERT INTO @tmpListTable 
                    (value) 
        VALUES     (Cast(Ltrim(Rtrim(@List)) AS VARCHAR(100))) 

      RETURN 
  END
```

Use the function:

```
DECLARE @idList NVARCHAR(max)=',1,2,3,4,5,6'; 

SELECT bookingid, 
       dogid 
FROM   booking 
WHERE  dogid IN (SELECT * 
                 FROM   [dbo].[Udf_stringtolist] (@idList, ',') 
                 ORDER  BY 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways.

1. Comma separated ids - which will lead to performance issue while split it
2. XML - is best approach.